# How to install a newer version of curl on a Docker base image shipped with an old version of curl please?

Tags: docker, curl

Small question regarding how to install a newer version of curl on an image pre-sipped with an old version of curl

I cannot touch or modify the base image.
Currently, the Dockerfile starts with:

```
FROM customdocker.com/my-organization/must/use/jdk/11:latest as BUILDER
```

And going inside the container, simple curl version will show a very old curl version.

I just want to use a newer one. I don't want to change anything else.
Hence, very naive, I went to change the Dockerfile by adding:

```
RUN yum install -y curl
```

While it is building, when I run the image, and execute a curl, I am left with the same old version of curl.

How to install, override the old version with a newer of my choice please?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of curl does yum install? Presumably you're using CentOS 7 and it's a very old curl. Most likely you'll need to compile your own version and copy it to the docker image, or there might be an alternate repo with more modern curl.

Comment: What version of curl does yum install? Presumably you're using CentOS 7 and it's a very old curl. -> Correct, 7.29

Comment: Most likely you'll need to compile your own version and copy it to the docker image -> How to do that please?

Comment: The curl download page https://curl.se/download.html links to these pre-built binaries for RHEL/CentOS that you can try first: https://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/ Push the RPM to the image and install from the Dockerfile using `RUN rpm -Uvh curl-7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64.rpm` (or whatever version you need). I'd suggest giving that a shot first instead of building your own binary at this point.

Comment: warning: /tmp/vault-secrets/curl-7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID b56a8bac: NOKEY

Comment: error: Failed dependencies:
 libcurl(x86-64) >= 7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7 is needed by curl-7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
 libmetalink.so.3()(64bit) is needed by curl-7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64

Comment: Sorry I hadn't tried the packages before. You can get libmetalink from epel, `yum install -y libmetalink" and then install the RPM `libcurl-7.74.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64.rpm` from the same curl mirror before installing the curl RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RUN sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/curl https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl/releases/download/v7.77.0/curl-amd64
RUN sudo chmod 0555 /usr/local/bin/curl
```